# HTML5 Canvas Clip using Arc is clipping wrong

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I have tried clipping an image using ctx.clip and ctx.arc like this:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(250, 250, 250, -Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 4);
ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

As you see I have set the start angle to -45 deg and the end angle to 45 deg, but what I get is a cut of circle/half moon, not a pac-man figure, as you would see if you filled the arc using ctx.fill.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ytoeg4k0/4/)

Why is this and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem, simply add ctx.moveTo(x, y) where x and y is the center of the arc, like this:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(250, 250);
ctx.arc(250, 250, 250, -Math.PI / 4, Math.PI / 4);
ctx.clip();
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ytoeg4k0/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing anything about HTML5 or JavaScript, I think you are just not closing the path properly. Add `ctx.lineTo(250,250);` after the arc: http://jsfiddle.net/7em21gvk/